# How can I send the data to another page without appending it in a URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario where a user when clicks on a link, they are directed to a page in which I want to add a code to fetch a variable and redirect to another page.

i.e. user clicks on `<a href="sample.tpl">click here</a>`

on sample.tpl I want to write a code to redirect him to another page

```
<script>
window.location="http://example.com/?page_id=10"
```

**but I want to send a variable too on this new link without appending it to the URL for security reasons.**

How can I do it with some safe procedure?

Do ask me questions if it is not clear.

Comment: Did you try saving that in a cookie then accessing it in the other page ?

Comment: Is the target page yours or not? What you mean by **security reasons**?

Comment: yes target page is mine, and for cookies what if cookies are disabled

Comment: It may help if you explain exactly what you are trying to do and why, there may be a better complete solution. Not much is truly secure in the webworld, unless you're using a form over SSL.

Comment: actually i want only the registered users to see that page, but that user authentication comes from another database. so i don't want it to be appendid to url as anyone will come and access the page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a form with `method="post"`, a `hidden` input with the value you want to pass and a `submit` button styled as a regular link (if you want to also manually send the form).

Then just submit the form manually or programmatically through the `submit()` method

---

Example (with automatic redirect after 3 seconds after page load)
http://jsbin.com/avacoj/1/edit

Html

```
<form method="post" action="http://mydomain.com/" id="f">
   <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="10">
   <noscript><button type="submit">Continue</button></noscript> /* see below */
</form>
```

Js

```
window.onload = function() {
  var frm = document.getElementById('f');
  setTimeout(function() {
      frm.submit();
  }, 3000);
};
```

As a side note you may consider to insert a `submit` button inside `<noscript></noscript>` tag so the redirect will be possibile even when js is not available on the user device, so the page is still accessible.

Comment: good idea, let me try it and then will be back to comment it or mark it as answer,
meanwhile if you can provide me with an example , will be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Further to Fabrizio's answer someone has written a javascript function which will allow you to build the form and send it via `POST` at runtime.

`POST` is like `GET` (Where the variable is appended to the url) except the variable is sent via the headers. It is still possible to fake a `POST` request so you must perform some kind of validation on the data.

```
function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default, if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Used like so:

```
post_to_url("http://mydomain.com/", {'page_id':'10'}, "post");
```

**Source:** [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit#answer-133997)